# I have a complicated density function, how to find the constant?

Tags: probability

Say, I have a density function: $f(x)=a e^{-((x-c)^2-b^2)^2}$ and $x$ can take any value in the real line. Obviously, I want to figure out the relation between $a$, $c$ and $b$ to make its integral to $1$. Can anyone provide some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear there is no closed form for what you're searching, but I might be wrong!

You can anyway simplify the setting a bit, noticing that the parameter $c$ only shifts the function along the $x$-axis, so you can take WLOG $c=0$. Also, since the parameter $b$ has a symmetric role (i.e. if you replace $b$ with $-b$ the function does not change) you can work only on the following constraint

\begin{equation}
2a\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-(x^2-b^2)^2} dx = 1
\end{equation}

with $b\geq 0$ and $a>0$.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I also noticed such simplification. But still find it hard to compute the expression you mentioned above.

Comment: You might try with Wolfram Alpha, but I guess there's no closed form.